# jQuery core.js "+i" statement, mistake or trick?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In jQuery core.js, [currently, line 260](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L260)

this.slice( i, +i + 1 );

is the "+i" statement a mistake or some fancy trickery I can't find any mention of?

Comment: I think is simple casting to integer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's a quick way to convert `i` to a number.  This matters because `+` means something different if it is a string to if it is a number.  For instance:

```
var i = "1";
console.log(i + 1); // "11"
console.log(+i + 1); // 2
```

It's basically a shortcut for `parseInt(i, 10)`.

Comment: One thing you should take note of about the differences between the `+` notation and `parseInt()` is that `parseInt()` will get all numeric characters from the beginning of the string until it bumps into something non-numeric. `var i = '22i'; alert(parseInt(i,10));` is `22` while `var i = '22i'; alert(+i)` is `NaN`. +1 though :D

Comment: +1, This is called the [+ unary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#.2b_%28Unary_Plus%29)

Comment: Thanks all, found this nice tutorial about type conversion http://www.jibbering.com/faq/notes/type-conversion/#tcNumber after also coming across inv = !!inv; in jQuery core and not understanding it. @Gaby, totally would have found the answer without asking if I had used the term 'unary operator' when searching, I know these terms, for some reason I don't use them in searches.